# Updating Product Status msg shows (cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiqgS.jpg)Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdpFD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question as text, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.